# applescript get only file name of a folder

Tags: applescript

I have the following script that list the contents (files and folder) of a folder

```
 set the_files to (list folder (choose folder) without invisibles)
```

e.g folder root has a file text1.txt and folders subroot2 and subroot3

but how can I get just the file name (only text1.txt) of a folder root (exclude subroot2 and subroot3)? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    files of folder (choose folder) -- Finder file objects
    name of files of folder (choose folder) -- names of files
end tell
```