# applescript get file name for given path

Tags: applescript

I just got [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274722/applescript-get-only-file-name-of-a-folder/20275209?noredirect=1#20275209) to get file name of a chosen folder.

```
 tell application "Finder"
 name of files of folder (choose folder) -- names of files
 end tell
```

However, I can't get this working for a give path, like this one

```
 set myfile to name of files of folder "~/Downloads/test/"
```

I played around a lot with POSIX path and others, but I can't get this working. Could you please help me again, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
tell application "System Events"

    set downloadsFolder to path to downloads folder as text
    -- display dialog downloadsFolder

end tell

tell application "Finder"

    set myFileNames to name of files of folder (downloadsFolder & "test:")
    log myFileNames

end tell
```

**ADDITION:**

```
set thisLocation to "/Volumes/Data/"

tell application "Finder"

    set myFileNames to name of files of folder (thisLocation as POSIX file)
    log myFileNames

end tell
```

Comment: I can't get this working for external volumes, e.g., set downloadsFolder to path to "volumes:Data:" as text

Comment: BTW AS Editor has built-in code snippets, CTRL-CLICK into a script to see them.

Comment: I don't get the use of log in the script, we can see the result then why do we need log? thanks

Comment: You can just delete that line with the log. I usually insert them for educational purposes.